# Passing not as a variable

Tags: ruby

I have two functions, each of which pulls items from an array while asking if a certain value is present or not. How could I create a method that can be flipped according to whether I'm asking if the value is present or not? The `(!)` below is what I'd like to pass as a variable.

```
ary.select{ |item| (!)item.my_value.nil? }
```

Is it possible to pass not to as a variable, somewhat like multiplying something by `x` where `x` could be `1` or `-1`?

Comment: something like `ary.reject { |item| item.my_value.nil? }` ? If not then I didn't get your question :)

Comment: That would still require that I have two functions that do basically the same thing. I'd like to use one function whose purpose can be flipped.

Comment: Well. Then `var = '!'; ary.select{ |item| item.my_value.nil?.public_send(var) }` is what you want..

Comment: This is essentially what I was looking for, but I was hoping Ruby had an elegant way to handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume this is in general terms and you are wondering how to pass something that you can use in the implementation of your function to reverse it. Two strategies:

1. Ruby metaprogramming. You can use the `BasicObject#!` and `Object#itself`:

<

```
def values_from(array, post_mutator:)
  array.select { |item| item.nil?.public_send(post_mutator) }
end

array = [1, nil, :b, nil, nil, 'foo']
values_from(array, post_mutator: :itself) # => [nil, nil, nil]
values_from(array, post_mutator: :!)      # => [1, :b, "foo"]
```

2. Boolean algebra. Basically, you want to find an operation `.`, for which:

> x . true = x
>
> x . false = -x

All possibilities are:

> true, true => true
>
> false, false => true
>
> false, true => false
>
> true, false => false

Which obviously leaves the `.` to be equality. Therefore:

```
def values_from(array, switcher)
  array.select { |item| item.nil? == switcher }
end

array = [1, nil, :b, nil, nil, 'foo']
values_from(array, true)  # => [nil, nil, nil]
values_from(array, false) # => [1, :b, "foo"]
```

Answer (score 1):

[ndn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32290147/1153437) addresses how to do this with Ruby meta-programming, but I was hoping for something a little more elegant, so I ended up addressing this by adding to `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` (with a RoR initializer).

```
class TrueClass
  def *(value)
    !!value
  end
end

class FalseClass
  def *(value)
    !value
  end
end
```

So I can do the following, which feels a bit more natural.

```
def select_from_ary(present)
  ary.select{ |item| present * item.my_value.nil? }
end
```

Comment: I think `select` and `reject` are more readable versions of doing same thing.    I would stay away from unnecessary tricks that can confuse future maintainers of the code

Comment: *"I didn't want to use meta-programming" - said he, while monkey patching boolean classes*. xd Btw, I like your idea, but I would have created my own objects with such method and pass them, instead of monkey patching.

Comment: Agreed, didn't feel great about the monkey patching.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function called `presence?` that returns true when you checking the item is present and false when you're checking it's absent then:

```
ary.select{ |item| !!item.my_value == presence? }
```

Or as a method where the Boolean is passed in:

```
def get_value_presence(boolean presence?)
 ary.select{ |item| !!item.my_value == presence? }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the `trues`and `falses` - that is what [partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) does:

```
array = [1, nil, :b, nil, nil, 'foo']
nils, non_nils =  array.partition{|item| item.nil?} # or: array.partition(&:nil?)
```